# Using LINQ to query properties of an inner IList

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below method returns an IList of 'SomeClass', which has property called IList.

What I am looking for is if 'Status' property of IList is 'true', I wanted to get the values of IList. I can easily do this using foreach loop, but I am planning to use LINQ for this.

**Definitions**:

*Method:*

```
IList<SomeClass> SomeMethod()

public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass();

    public IList<SomeInnerClass> ActualData { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

public class SomeInnerClass
{
    public SomeInnerClass();

    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*What I have now:*

```
var abc = IList<SomeClass> SomeMethod();

foreach (var outer in abc)
{
    foreach (var inner in outer.ActualData)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what's preventing you to write `WHERE` and `SELECT`

Comment: You have no code inside your foreach loops. What are you trying to accomplish? Please provide sample data input and output.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to select the `SomeInnerClass` objects themselves, you could use a [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx) call to filter your outer collection and then a [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) call to retrieve either the `ActualData` or `SomeInnerClass` objects respectively :

```
// Get your list
var list = SomeMethod(); 
// Pull out on the SomeInnerClasses where Status is true
var output = list.Where(l => l.Status)
                 .SelectMany(l => l.ActualData)
                 .ToList();
```